# iOS animation skips elements

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

I've implemented a welcome screen which has a collection view with a set of circular images which are the user accounts. When the user clicks on one of the cells, I create a new UIImageView (not really create, but just move one UIImageView which is hidden) to the top of the screen, hide the collectionview and move up a keyboard frame (which is initially below the view, y=view.frame.height).
If I do not set the image property of the newly created UIImageView to the image of the original cell, everything works as it should. However, if I set the image, the keyboard does not show the first time. All the other animations happen without any problem. Only the keyboard frame move does not happen. The second time I try the animation, however, everything works as it should (The image property does not change anymore, as it's the same image). If I click another cell, the bug repeats itself until I click the cell the second time, in which time it works as it should.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UserCell
    userLoginImageView.hidden = false //UIImageView I keep around for the animation
    userLoginImageView.frame = cell.convertRect(cell.userImage.frame, toView: self.view) //Move it on top of the cell that was just clicked
    userLoginImageView.image = cell.userImage.image //This line causes the problem. If I comment it out, everything works perfectly.
    userLoginImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    resetPassword(false)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options:
        UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.keyboardView.frame = CGRectMake(self.keyboardViewShownFrame!.minX, self.keyboardViewShownFrame!.minY, self.keyboardViewShownFrame!.width, self.keyboardViewShownFrame!.height) //Slide up the keyboard. This is the only animation that doesn't happen when I change the image
            self.userLoginImageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2 - 45, 40, 90, 90)
            self.collectionView.alpha = 0
            self.welcomeLabel.alpha = 0
            self.backButton.alpha = 1
            self.enterPinLabel.alpha = 1
            for view in self.passwordViews {
                view.alpha = 1
            }
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Welcome screen:

[image]

After first time clicking:

[image]

Clicking second time (image has loaded):

[image]

Comment: You specifically mentioned setting the image to that of the original cell. Have you tried setting it to a different image? Also, try printing `self.keyboardViewShownFrame` and see what it shows.

Comment: Yes I did try that. The same thing happens. If I print self.keyboardViewShownFrame during the animation block, it appears as changed. However in the competition callback, it shows the original value. Just commenting the line about the image makes it work as it should. @AdamH.

Comment: It appears as changed? You mean that if you print out `self.keyboardViewShownFrame` in the animation block, then it is not the frame that you actually want? And just to clarify, you are not using Autolayout on these views, correct? Because that could complicate matters further.

Comment: If I print out self.keyboardViewShownFrame in the animation block, it appears as changed (i.e. the value I want it to take). However, in the completition closure, it reverts back to it's old value. Moreover, it doesn't appear at all in the screen. I am using in fact using AutoLayout. However I don't believe it is the problem as everything works perfectly when I do not change the image attribute of the UIImageView I just created. @AdamH.

Comment: From what I can tell, `self.keyboardViewShownFrame` should not change at all. It should hold the value of what the keyboard's frame should be when it is on the screen. The only `CGRect` that should change is `self.keyboardView.frame`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the variable name. I was always printing self.keyboardView.frame. self.keyboardViewShownFrame never changes.
In hte animation block, self.keyboardView.frame changes to the value of self.keyboardViewShownFrame, however, in the completition block, it reverts back to it's value (animation was not performed) whenever I have changed the image. If I do not change the image (i.e. click the same user again), it animates properly.

Comment: I am at a loss as to why that would occur. The only thing I can think of is that loading the image into the `UIImageView` the first time blocks the main thread from executing the animation. Perhaps a temporary fix until a better solution is found would be to set the image at a different time. Sorry about that.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought of as well. However, I cannot understand why this only happens to the keyboardview. I am doing many other animations, but only this one suffers. I've tried disabling all the other animations as well, still no luck.

Comment: Maybe try adding the image setting as a block to the main operation queue, then the rest of the code as well in the next block to the main operation queue.

Comment: Just tried that. I think it creates some kind of race condition, where sometimes the imageView skips the animation and sometimes it's the keyboard view. Strange.